# Project Euler problems which are not so math oriented

Tags: algorithm

I have started to solve PE problems a year ago, but within this year, I realised, that finding a problem which would be fun for me to think of is quite hard. I would like to solve problems more related with classic algorithms (graph theory, game theory, dynamic programming, divide and conquer...) and not so much of number theory and geometry (althought I like them too, but there was so much of them so far).

Any tips? (first 50 problems already solved and second half of first hudnred almost too, so I would like to get some tips for problems from 100-200. 200+ are quite hard for me, I think)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any sites that do Python programming challenges similar to ProjectEuler, only maybe not so math oriented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697615/are-there-any-sites-that-do-python-programming-challenges-similar-to-projecteuler)

Comment: can't you just look at the problems one by one and reject those you're not interested in?

Comment: @marcog Thanks for notification!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From 100+, intersected with the ones that I've solved, those that might be interesting to you are:

- [#107](http://projecteuler.net/problem=107) (graph theory)
- [#114](http://projecteuler.net/problem=114), [#115](http://projecteuler.net/problem=115), [#116](http://projecteuler.net/problem=116), [#117](http://projecteuler.net/problem=117) (combinatorics, dynamic programming)
- [#122](http://projecteuler.net/problem=122) (some algebra, but hardly any)
- [#206](http://projecteuler.net/problem=206) (numerics, but hardly number theory)

Answer (score 7):

Try the following Project Euler questions:

- [185](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=185)
- [186](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=186)
- [212](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=212)
- [215](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=215)
- [237](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=237)

Comment: Wow, these are also looking very well. Thanks! Pity I cannot choose two answers accepted at once.

Answer (score 5):

[314 - The Mouse on the Moon](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=314)

Comment: I liked the Mouse books, and thought Problem 314 was an interesting one.  However, it may be considered geometry-based.

Answer (score 4):

There is PE page that lists details of [all problems on one page](http://projecteuler.net/show=all), which may make it easier to find problems that suit your interests.